# Return empty array from map instead of array with empty string

Tags: go

I have a map of ids that map to an array of strings as such `accountIDs := make(map[int64][]string, 0)` and in my response this looks like:

```
"AccountIDs": {
    "1": [
        "19565",
        "21423"
    ],
    "7": [
        ""
    ]
}
```

How can I return an empty array instead of an array of empty string?

Comment: looks like the value associated to `7` is a string slice of length 1, but without seeing your actual code, that's just a guess

Comment: Assign it to nil

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj `nil` serializes to `null` https://go.dev/play/p/GKw-5b0pMeG

Comment: If I assign to `nil` that doesn't give me an empty array. It gives me `null`. @blackgreen you are correct, I do have an empty an empty string, that is where the length comes from. I am trying to handle that.

Comment: Are you sure the array is empty before you serialize and respond?

Comment: Are you trying to marshal the map? I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but if that is what you are trying to do, I had a similar question a while back that was answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71252747/golang-go-how-to-marshal-struct-to-null-if-it-has-no-fields (You have to write your own marshaller)

If this is what you are trying to achieve and would like some elaboration, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value to `[]string{}`.

```
myMap[7] = []string{}
```

See [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ICJG5hN_HJT)